# Send data Failed using Serial comport 411f delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcomport

I have a Delphi 7 code that send sensor data values to a DSP TMS32F28069. The value send by Delphi is Hex file data. For example I send data:

F0;01;01;07;00;00;00;00;00;00;00;F7
from Delphi.

I use Comport 411f and actually when I use windows 10 64 bit english version everything is fine. But when I use windows 7 chinese 64 bit, the data that send never received by DSP. I have try on several notebook using windows 7 64 bit chinese version, and it has the same problem, no data received.
This is the code I wrote in Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.dxBarButton19Click(Sender: TObject);
var
j:array[1..12]of AnsiChar;
begin
   j[1]:=#$F0;j[2]:=#$01;j[3]:=#$01;j[4]:=#$07;j[5]:=#$00;j[6]:=#$00;j[7]:=#$00;j[8]:=#$00;j[9]:=#$00;j[10]:=#$00;j[11]:=#$00;j[12]:=#$F7;
   comport1.Open;
 for p:=1 to 12 do
   begin
     comport1.Write(j[p],1);
   end;
end;
```

Please give me any suggestion why this happened on windows 7 64 bit chinese version? because when I use windows 7 64 bit english version, it was also work fine.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried byte data `j:array[1..12] of Byte; ...  j[1]:=$F0;` - does problem remain?

Comment: I have tried but it keep remain  Mbo, do you have other suggestion?

Comment: Install http://www.sudt.com/en/ap/download.htm and check real transmitted data

Comment: Hi MBo, actually I have check with acces port, the data is coming out the right way and correct, but some how my DSP didn't receive any single data... 
But if I use access port to send data to DSP, The DSP was received the data. I have no idea about this.

Comment: It is magic? :) Check port settings in details. Check outcoming data packet more thoroughly..

Answer (score 0):

From [AnsiChar documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.AnsiChar)

> AnsiChar values are byte-sized (8-bits) characters ordered according to the locale character set, which is possibly multibyte. The first 256 Unicode characters correspond to the ANSI characters.

So it is affected by locale settings. Try to change it to byte.

Comment: I have tried and it keep remain, do you have other suggestion?